# How to connect to AWS MSK from Debezium connector using username and password

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, aws-msk

Here i'm trying to use Debezium Connector to Read data from RDS and publish it to AWS MSK.

All i could see is using AWS IAM based authentication everywhere but unfortunately my cloud engineering team is not willing to add IAM but provided basic auth (username and password) with a topic to publish.

I'm planning to use debezium/connect docker image so i can deploy it to EKS.

Is there any way to connect to MSK using username and password ?

Comment: It's not terribly clear what you're after, do you want to connect Debezium to the RDS database or do you want to see what's going on in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Debezium to connect to your RDS database, you must include database credentials (username and password) in your Debezium config. For example, check out the 'Required Config' docs for the Postgres connector: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-required-configuration-properties

You must supply `database.user`, `database.password`, and other related values.

If you want to connect to your MSK cluster, there are a couple of alternatives as described here: [Connecting to an Amazon MSK Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/client-access.html).

Answer (score 0):

For a username/password based authentication to MSK cluster best would be to use SASL SCRAM. See details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-password.html

Other authentication supported by MSK so far [JAN/31/2022] are:

- IAM auth
- mutual TLS - certificate based
- SASL SCRAM - username/password based

Comment: SASL/SCRAM is not available neither in AWS MSK connector console nor in CDK or Terraform. OP is asking about connecting the MSK connector to MSK cluster